# How do I programmatically play an MP3 on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, audio

I'd like to include an MP3 with my app and play it on demand.  Unfortunately I am not sure how to get started.  I keep reading about .caf files, but I am not sure what those are.

I am looking for a step by step, if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could also try the [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) utility Framework.

Answer (score 16):

Here is what I am doing to play mp3 in xCode 4.2:

1) Import `AVFoundation.framework` framework into your project

2) Adding: `#import "AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h"` into your project `ViewController.h` file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

3) Drag and drop your mp3 file `yoursoundfile.mp3` into your root project explorer

4) Modify `-(void)viewDidLoad`in `ViewController.m`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                         pathForResource:@"yoursoundfile"
                                         ofType:@"mp3"]];
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                                  initWithContentsOfURL:url
                                  error:nil];
    [audioPlayer play];
}
```

As soon as you start your program, it will play the sound. You can customize to fit your app by changing volume, or when to play, stop...

Answer (score 2):

Use afconvert in Terminal to convert your MP3 to a .caf.  man afconvert will tell you more.

Then

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: name ofType: @"caf"];

NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];

AVAudioPlayer *player = [super initWithContentsOfURL: fileURL error: nil];
[fileURL release];
[player play];
```

Comment: Great.  Where in the project do I drop the .caf file?  Into the resources folder?

Comment: Yes.  Resources folder is good.  You could have subfolders if you had multiples .cafs and wanted to keep them in their own folder.

Comment: One other thing to know is if you want to play the sound without any delay, you can call [player prepareToPlay] to preload it.  Calling [player stop] however, may unload it, forcing -play to reload it.  -pause, stops playback, and does not unload.  (You could manually set the player to play from the beginning after pausing)

Comment: This coding will not work for me. I given this in ViewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe look at: http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/audio-video/simple-way-to-play-mp3-audio-files and http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html?

Comment: Link #1 is cheating - I don't actually need an interface, just a sound.  Link #2 playing it on the Mac, not iPhone.

Comment: Hi AngryHacker: Yeah, I kind of figured the first link wasn't what you were going for - but I included it in case you were in fact looking for that.  As for the second link, there is a link to a "AudioStreamer" project on there, which includes the source to both the iPhone and the Mac version.