# How to play a downloaded mp3 file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, mp3, playback

I have downloaded a mp3 file from a server successfully, but the problem I encountered is, I don't know how to play that file..  Should I use AVAudioPlayer or AudioQueue to play the file?? I will be appreciate if you could post some sample code here.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296786/how-do-i-programmatically-play-an-mp3-on-an-iphone and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973902/play-mp3-files-with-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Both `AVAudioPlayer` and the Audio Queue API can be used to play MP3 files. The `AVAudioPlayer` is well documented and has a lot of sample code available. So why not give it  try first and if that does not work, post a more specific question here.

Comment: ok I'll give it a try, but my XCode told me that there is no provisioned iphone OS device is connected, I am struggling to this issue, do you have an idea of this problem??  my iphone FW is 3.1.3, Xcode is 3.2.2(pre-released)

Comment: I've finally play the MP3 file DL from server and store in the device successfully, but a weird issue happens sporadically, the error shows:

Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1685348671 "Operation could not be completed. (OSStatus error 1685348671.)"

the MP3 file couldn't be played and shows above error messages even though the file saved to the device without problem, can anyone tell me what I am missing??