# how to play an MP3 when a UIButton is tapped?

Tags: ios4, uibutton, mp3, avaudioplayer, iphone

Can anyone please give me sample code of how sound is played with a UIButton being tapped?

I would like to play an MP3 file using AVAudioPlayer

Comment: See [How do I programmatically play an MP3 on an iPhone?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296786/how-do-i-programmatically-play-an-mp3-on-an-iphone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should get you started. Add this to your view controller, then hook up the button to the playAudio action in interface builder.

in your header .h

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ClassName {
    ...
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

- (IBAction) playAudio;
```

in your .m

```
@synthesize audioPlayer;

- (IBAction) playAudio {
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"audio" withExtension: @"m4a"];
    if (!url){NSLog(@"file not found"); return;}
    NSError *error;
    self.audioPlayer = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error] autorelease];
    [audioPlayer play]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//ViewController.h ,write below code
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<AVAudioRecorderDelegate,AVAudioPlayerDelegate>

//assign property to player
 @property(nonatomic,retain) AVAudioPlayer *player;

//then write in ViewController.m file in ViewDidLoad Method

NSError *soundError;
NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"soundFileName" ofType:@"mp3"]; //.mp3 file for player
NSURL *file=[[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:path]; //path
_player=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:file error:&soundError]; //player Object

if(_player == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"player is empty because of %@",soundError);
}
else
{
    [_player play];
    _player.volume=1.0;
    [_player setDelegate:self];

}

// for stop player you can use 
    // [_player stop]; //uncomment this line when you wants to stop it.
```