# playing a mp3 file in iOS app

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I can't figure out how to play a music file in an iPhone game.

Im creating a Game and I am trying to figure out how to play music whenever the app is launched.

I tried this:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"musicamenu" ofType:@"mp3"];

    AVAudioPlayer *theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

    [theAudio play];


}
```

Comment: you may want to look at this previous question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296786/how-do-i-programmatically-play-an-mp3-on-an-iphone

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is how you do it. In your v1AppDelegate.h file add

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface v1AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    AVAudioPlayer *myAudioPlayer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *myAudioPlayer;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

Now in your v1AppDelegate.m file add this

```
#import "v1AppDelegate.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@implementation v1AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

@synthesize myAudioPlayer;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    //start a background sound
    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Soothing_Music2_Long" ofType: @"mp3"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:soundFilePath ];    
    myAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
    myAudioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1; //infinite loop
    [myAudioPlayer play];


    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

If you wish to stop or start this music from anywhere else in your code then simply add this

```
#import "v1AppDelegate.h"    
- (IBAction)stopMusic
    {
        v1AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [appDelegate.myAudioPlayer stop];
    }


    - (IBAction)startMusic
    {
        v1AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [appDelegate.myAudioPlayer play];
    }
```

Comment: I GOT IT WORKING FINEE!! THANK YOU EVERYONE!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to add the play music method in `applicationDidBecomeActive:` method. Because you want the music played every time the app is launched. Note you should hold a reference to the player. Else the music will not be played.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Play music on another queue so that the main queue is not blocked.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self playMusic];
    });
}

- (void)playMusic
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"done" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    [self.player play];
}
```

Comment: "Note you should hold a reference to the player. Else the music will not be played." saved me

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 3.1 :

Use this two imports :

```
import AVFoundation
import AudioToolbox
```

Create a reference for your AVAudioPlayer :

```
private var mAudioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer?
```

Use this function for play a sound you are storing in your app :

```
func onTapSound(){
        let soundFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "slap_placeholder.wav", ofType: nil)
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: soundFile!)
        self.mAudioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url as URL)
        self.mAudioPlayer?.play()
}
```